# What is the outcome unit of $\frac{Q}{\rho c_p}$ in heat equation with diffusion?

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis, si-units

What is the outcome unit of $\frac{Q}{\rho c_p}$ (an internal heat source)?

In context of (unsteady) diffusion of heat and heat equation.

Comment: Can you show the whole equation?  Also, what is "p"?  I'm guessing that it is density, but the typical symbol for density is rho, not p.

Comment: The units would be K/s if Q is the rate of heat generation per unit volume

Comment: @DavidWhite This expression seems very standard in the literature. A web search brings up many examples with this. Consider e.g. https://www.nuclear-power.com/nuclear-engineering/heat-transfer/thermal-conduction/heat-conduction-equation/

Comment: @ChetMiller It's actually quite likely yes that the units are heat unit per second.